# having issue update and upgrade

Tags: command-line, dpkg, dependencies, 20.10

when i try to update & upgrade command on terminal i get this message:

```
Hit:1 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl1.1 : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not installed or
                      debconf-2.0
 net.downloadhelper.coapp : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

after `sudo apt --fix-broken install` command:

i get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adduser apt apt-utils ca-certificates dbus debconf debconf-i18n dpkg gpgv libacl1 libapparmor1 libapt-pkg6.0 libasound2 libasyncns0 libaudit-common libaudit1 libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libcap-ng0 libdb5.3
  libdbus-1-3 libdrm-common libdrm2 libexpat1 libffi8ubuntu1 libflac8 libgbm1 libgcrypt20 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0 libhogweed6 libidn2-0 liblocale-gettext-perl liblz4-1 liblzma5
  libnettle8 libogg0 libp11-kit0 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam0g libpcre2-8-0 libpulse0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libseccomp2 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsepol1 libsndfile1 libstdc++6
  libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libudev1 libunistring2 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1
  libwayland-server0 libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxcursor1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxxf86vm1 libzstd1 lsb-base
  openssl passwd perl-base tar ubuntu-keyring update-motd x11-common xkb-data zlib1g
Suggested packages:
  perl ecryptfs-utils apt-doc aptitude | synaptic | wajig dpkg-dev gnupg | gnupg2 | gnupg1 powermgmt-base default-dbus-session-bus | dbus-session-bus debconf-doc debconf-utils whiptail | dialog
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libgtk3-perl libnet-ldap-perl debconf-kde-helper debsig-verify gnupg libasound2-plugins rng-tools gnutls-bin libpam-doc pulseaudio sensible-utils bzip2 ncompress xz-utils
  tar-scripts tar-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adduser apt apt-utils ca-certificates dbus debconf debconf-i18n dpkg gpgv libacl1 libapparmor1 libapt-pkg6.0 libasound2 libasyncns0 libaudit-common libaudit1 libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libcap-ng0 libdb5.3
  libdbus-1-3 libdrm-common libdrm2 libexpat1 libffi8ubuntu1 libflac8 libgbm1 libgcrypt20 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgpg-error-l10n libgpg-error0 libhogweed6 libidn2-0 liblocale-gettext-perl liblz4-1 liblzma5
  libnettle8 libogg0 libp11-kit0 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam0g libpcre2-8-0 libpulse0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libseccomp2 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsepol1 libsndfile1 libstdc++6
  libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libudev1 libunistring2 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1
  libwayland-server0 libwrap0 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxcursor1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxxf86vm1 libzstd1 lsb-base
  openssl passwd perl-base tar ubuntu-keyring update-motd x11-common xkb-data zlib1g
0 upgraded, 93 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16,8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 71,0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 32%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 64%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 96%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcom-err2:amd64:
 libcom-err2:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcom-err2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkrb5support0:amd64:
 libkrb5support0:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkrb5support0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libk5crypto3:amd64:
 libk5crypto3:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libk5crypto3:amd64 depends on libkrb5support0 (>= 1.16); however:
  Package libkrb5support0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libk5crypto3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkeyutils1:amd64:
 libkeyutils1:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.14); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libkeyutils1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcom-err2:amd64
 libkrb5support0:amd64
 libk5crypto3:amd64
 libkeyutils1:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can i solve the issue?

`dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=============================-==================-============-=======================================================
iU  debconf-i18n                  1.5.74             all          full internationalization support for debconf
iU  libc6:amd64                   2.32-0ubuntu3      amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
iU  libc6:i386                    2.32-0ubuntu3      i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
iU  libcom-err2:amd64             1.45.6-1ubuntu1    amd64        common error description library
iU  libcom-err2:i386              1.45.6-1ubuntu1    i386         common error description library
iU  libcrypt1:amd64               1:4.4.16-1ubuntu1  amd64        libcrypt shared library
iU  libcrypt1:i386                1:4.4.16-1ubuntu1  i386         libcrypt shared library
iU  libgcc-s1:amd64               10.2.0-13ubuntu1   amd64        GCC support library
iU  libgcc-s1:i386                10.2.0-13ubuntu1   i386         GCC support library
iU  libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64        1.17-10ubuntu0.1   amd64        MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - krb5 GSS-API Mechanism
iU  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386         1.17-10ubuntu0.1   i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - krb5 GSS-API Mechanism
iU  libk5crypto3:amd64            1.17-10ubuntu0.1   amd64        MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Crypto Library
iU  libk5crypto3:i386             1.17-10ubuntu0.1   i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Crypto Library
iU  libkeyutils1:amd64            1.6.1-2ubuntu1     amd64        Linux Key Management Utilities (library)
iU  libkeyutils1:i386             1.6.1-2ubuntu1     i386         Linux Key Management Utilities (library)
iU  libkrb5-3:amd64               1.17-10ubuntu0.1   amd64        MIT Kerberos runtime libraries
iU  libkrb5-3:i386                1.17-10ubuntu0.1   i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries
iU  libkrb5support0:amd64         1.17-10ubuntu0.1   amd64        MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Support library
iU  libkrb5support0:i386          1.17-10ubuntu0.1   i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Support library
iU  libnsl2:amd64                 1.3.0-0ubuntu3     amd64        Public client interface for NIS(YP) and NIS+
iU  libnsl2:i386                  1.3.0-0ubuntu3     i386         Public client interface for NIS(YP) and NIS+
iU  libnss-nis:amd64              3.1-0ubuntu4       amd64        NSS module for using NIS as a naming service
iU  libnss-nis:i386               3.1-0ubuntu4       i386         NSS module for using NIS as a naming service
iU  libnss-nisplus:amd64          1.3-0ubuntu4       amd64        NSS module for using NIS+ as a naming service
iU  libnss-nisplus:i386           1.3-0ubuntu4       i386         NSS module for using NIS+ as a naming service
iU  libssl1.1:amd64               1.1.1f-1ubuntu4.3  amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
iU  libssl1.1:i386                1.1.1f-1ubuntu4.3  i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
iU  libtirpc3:amd64               1.2.6-1build1      amd64        transport-independent RPC library
iU  libtirpc3:i386                1.2.6-1build1      i386         transport-independent RPC library
iU  net.downloadhelper.coapp:i386 1.6.1              i386         Video DownloadHelper companion app
iU  teamviewer                    15.16.8            amd64        Remote control and meeting solution.
```

Comment: "sudo dpkg -l | grep debconf" gives no output

Comment: sorry, this can not be resolved in reasonable time in my opinion. there are too many essential packages are involved (libc6=heart of linux) Save your data install anew. I will delete my answer.

Comment: thank you, i will consider fresh install :)